# Variance-covariance matrix of a linear regression model

Tags: matrices, statistics, regression

In finding the covariance matrix of a linear regression model I don't understand this step:
$$
E[(b-\beta)(b-\beta)']=E[(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon\epsilon'X(X'X)^{-1}]
$$
where we've been given that 
$$
b=(X'X)^{-1}X'y
$$
and
$$
y=Xb+\epsilon
$$

Could someone give me the steps between?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $y = X\beta + \epsilon$?